# Is CodeDeploy requires to keep deployment scripts in build archive?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, continuous-integration, aws-code-deploy

I'm tried to deploy my build archive hosted on S3 and getting the following error during beforeInstall:

```
Script does not exist at specified location: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/47208456650-458497-4028-97qa6-ef3a7sa30fa96f/d-0S472LBGI/deployment-archive/deployment/backup.sh
```

My build archive contains only sources. Build scripts are permanently located on my server.

AppSpec.yml looks like

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

files:
  - source: /build.tgz
    destination: /var/www/proj/deployment <- deployment scripts are here
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: backup.sh
      runas: root
      timeout: 300
  AfterInstall:
    - location: deploy.sh
      runas: root
      timeout: 300
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: applicationStart.sh
      runas: root
      timeout: 300
```

Comment: Just add to @Castrohenge, the location of the script is relative to the source bundle, NOT the destination folder. That's why it couldn't find the backup.sh script

Answer (score 0):

I've always included my deployment scripts in the package. Try setting the location to an absolute value. eg. `/var/www/proj/deployment/backup.sh`

The `source` refers to a file/directory that is in your package. The package will be extracted to the location:

`/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/47208456650-458497-4028-97qa6-ef3a7sa30fa96f/d-0S472LBGI/deployment-archive/deployment`

The 'destination' indicates where you want to copy the file/directory.

You can specify multiple files. eg:

```
files:
  - source: Config/config.txt
    destination: /webapps/Config
  - source: source
    destination: /webapps/myApp
```

Here are the AppSpec docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref-structure.html